# Find & Replace - Google Sheets Script after GetData

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-sheets

I'm having some trouble with my script. Basically, that works getting data from one course and inputting the values to one Sheet. That's working perfectly. But when one of my students input 'enter' command at that course, I have trouble to read it in Excel. 
SO, I have to find (it's a regular Expression: \r\n|\n|\r) and replace the enter at Google Spreadsheet and change it for "; ". Works perfectly doing it manually, but I can't do it by script. Here the piece:

```
     //  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "DATA";

//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app 
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version' 
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously) 
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action 
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}
 function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("CHANGED BY SECURITY REASON"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){


    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}


function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("1Un5A61M8CJDBGDAB-Tx-lYgKYaVB2RSfn9QAQ5Q-sZs", doc.getId());
}
```

I tried this and worked well, but needs a trigger that's play only minute per minute. Not ok.. And change just the first value from the cell. Sometimes there's more than one at same cell:

```
function Replace() {
    var redeletar = new RegExp("\r\n|\n|\r");
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
        .getRange('A1:CH');
      range.setValues(range.getValues()
        .map(function (r) {
            return r.map(function (c) {
            //Replace string
              return c.toString().replace(redeletar, ";");
             });
     }));
}
```

Any idea to play this script at same time after the Sheet receive de data from my course AND play it recursively?

Thanks so mucho

Comment: Perhaps I don't know what you are talking about but I see no need for recursion there.  Perhaps you can provide an example of what your trying to do.

Comment: Yes, if the user input at that course (e-learning) four lines, when I run that script, that gonna remove only the first line break of the cel, but I need to remove all the breaks, just after the values come from my course. That need to happen because after that I have another excel file that reads the info and the way there is now, Excel separate each line into new cells, but can't happen

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is the global flag as shown below:

```
function Replace() 
 {
   var re = /(\r\n|\n|\r")/g;
   var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
   range.setValues(range.getValues().map(function (r){return r.map(function (c){return c.toString().replace(re, ";");});}));
 }
```

I think this will make all of the replacements rather than just the first ones;

Comment: The code is perfect to replace everything, thank you SO much. BUT I can't run it from the code above, just after the catch(e). I really need that code run after all data was get. Any idea, @cooper